# Issue on HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() for PowerBI

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am following the example of powerbi walkthrough Get a dataset to add rows into a Power BI table on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data-add-rows and im encountering an issue when accessing HttpRequest.GetResponse()

All azure settings are already set and was able to successfully generate a token through code

```
    string token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new 
    Uri(redirectUri)).AccessToken;
```

but i'm encountering an issue on the GetRespone of HttpRequest saying Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
    using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //-->raises an issue Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```